# Queue models with arrival rate equal to the service rate?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, queueing-theory

What happens in a queue system with arrival rate $\lambda$ equal to the service rate $\nu$?
It is possible to find its equilibrium distribution?

Comment: Assuming you mean an M/M/1 queue? No invariant distribution: the Markov chain is non-explosive but null recurrent

Comment: What does it mean null recurrent?

Comment: The state is recurrent, but the mean return time is infinite, i.e. $\mathbb E_x[\inf\{t\geq J_1\mid X_t=x\}]=\infty$ where $J_1$ is the time of the first jump